# Using WIX want to make a package that will update an existing installation and also install the application for the first time

Tags: wix

In various places I have read statements similar to "an update packaged as 
a full MSI package can behave as a first-time installation if a 
particular user does not have an earlier version of your product 
installed".

But it is proving difficult to do this.

I have an install package that installs nicely.  But when I add the Upgrade element below, it doesn't do a first time install any more.

```
<Upgrade Id="DE3F65C6-FAAF-4FE0-8D3A-87E4A1F5E36F">
    <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Minimum="4.1.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="5.0.0.7" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONFOUND" />
</Upgrade>
```

The Id above is the same as in the UpgradeCode attribute of the Product element.  I'm sure there's something I should do in that Upgrade element, but can anyone tell me what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does StackOverflow award a "Hits forehead while exclaiming I'm an idiot" badge?

The problem was nowhere near where I was looking.  Just so that anyone else looking for the answer to my question comes here, the real answer is to include that  element which I referred to in my question (obviously with Id and version numbers modified for your particular  situation).

My package also has

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

It may not be absolutely necessary, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

One potential issue you might see here is the fact that Windows Installer only cares about the first 3 values in a version number. Microsoft say that the fourth number is purely for internal build tracking, and therefore released installers should not care about it.

So Windows Installer sees 5.0.0.1 as the same version as 5.0.0.30.

Also, unless you need some kind of complicated upgrade logic, I would suggest possibly using the `MajorUpgrade` element instead, as it removes a lot of the pain of just authoring a package that will do standard Major Upgrades. The documentation on it can be found [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_majorupgrade.htm)

Another point of confusion could be the fact that while under the covers the installer will essentially treat a Major Upgrade as an uninstall followed by a fresh reinstall, the UI you have set up may not behave in the same way, especially if you are just using one of the default UI Dialog sets.

Comment: Thanks, ChrisPatrick.  I have been using an old version of WIX, and have just upgraded to the latest, which supports that MajorUpgrade element.  If have <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="My Message" />, but still no joy I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh, and for the record, I am testing with a silent install, so the UI shouldn't really be an issue.  And as to the version, I don't really mind the last digit being ignored.

Comment: What behaviour do you get when you try to upgrade?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't very clear:the upgrading works fine, it's the first time install that doesn't.The log shows a number of entries like "Action start <time> FindRelatedProducts . Return value 1."  (Also for AppSearch, LaunchConditions, ValidateProductID, ConstInitialize, FileCost).  Nothing else in the log.  It does perform a number of the functions I wanted it to (like removing files from a previous non-MSI install and making some registry entries), but the <Component>s comprising the app are not installed.  And it is really only the <MajorUpgrade> element that makes it differ from an install.

Comment: Ahhhh, OK, how are you running the install? Also, it might be worth using the verbose logging if you aren't already. It sounds to me like it isn't detecting it as a first-time install properly. Maybe something has been left over by a previous installation?

Comment: msiexec /i xpressdox.msi /qn  /l* silent.log
I tried it with /l*v and there's a lot of stuff but it doesn't mean anything to me - I'm trying to see if I can see anything in it.

Comment: About 60 lines down in the log is "Product not registered: beginning first-time install".  Which is heartening.  The very last line of the log is "Action start 16:45:47: CostFinalize."  It almost sounds like the msiexec just gave up at that point.  Normally the log ends with something about the success or failure of the install.

Comment: That's odd. It definitely seems like something is interrupting it. Either that or the install was still running when you opened the log file?

Comment: ChrisPatrick - thank you for all your efforts.  Please see my blushing answer below.